# Implementing digital goods express checkout without javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, paypal

Is it possible to implement express checkout for digital goods without having to use javascript? I want my website not to depend on clients having javascript enabled and can live with customers being redirected to PayPal's pages to authorize payment. Can I simply redirect the user to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout &token=APIToken instead of https://www.paypal.com/incontext?token=APIToken after the call to setexpresscheckout if I mark the transaction as a digital goods one (noshipping=1, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: yes.

1. Don't change anything about your initial API call
2. Like you mentioned, after you get your API token from paypal redirect the user to: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=APIToken
3. If you are transitioning from js, remember to *remove* the paypal script tag and the code that converts your link into a popup:

   new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: "link_id" })